# Finding the z score and p-value of a binomial distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

Emily is a big fan of lady gaga, and 20% of the songs on her ipod are lady gaga songs.  Suppose Emily has her ipod on shuffle and repeat mode, which can be assumed to mean that each song to be played always has the same 20% chance to be a lady gaga song.

What is the approximate probability that at least 14 of 75 songs that Emily listens to will be from lady gaga?

I understand I have to calculate the z score and find the corresponding p value with 1-P(z), but should I use the normal approximation to the binomial?  Namely, $\mathcal{N}\left(np, \sqrt{np(1-p)}\right)$?  I'm confused, because the answer lists $np$, and $np(1-p)$ instead of $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.  Where does this deviation come from?

Answer (score 4):

Two points here

1. You should use the exact binomial approach. You can get it in Excel or any statistical program / language (R, SAS, Stata, SPSS). In Excel `BINOMDIST(13,75,20%,TRUE)` gives the probability of 13 or fewer songs being from Lady Gaga. One minus that will give you the other tail (remember that the binomial is discrete, therefore the cutpoint matters)
2. The difference between the $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ and $np(1-p)$ is that the former is describing the normal in terms of its mean and standard deviation, while the latter is doing in terms of its mean and variance. Just a definition.